# Жесткая верстка

Tags: html, css, javascript

Кто знает, как подогнать фиксированный сайт к различным разрешениям монитора. У меня сайт на `1280x1024` выглядит нормально, но при меньшем разрешении становится шире окна, а при процентной верстке блоки сьезжают друг на друга.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Минимум, четыре варианта:

1. Сделать его 1024px шириной.
2. Сделать его-таки резиновым, но с минимальной шириной обрамляющего блока 1024px.
3. Забить на всех, у кого монитор меньше 1280: планшеты и телефоны привычные, они умеют подгонять сайт, либо показывать его частями, мониторов таких уже почти нет, на телевизорах сайты смотрят только злобные буратины
4. Использовать Float:left/right, тогда блоки не будут наезжать, а будут "спрыгивать" вниз.

Странный вопрос.

Comment: Нет, inline block а не float

Answer (score 0):

По мне так самый нормальный вариант вот:
[elliotjaystocks.com](http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/css-transitions-media-queries/)

(изменяй размеры окна чтобы увидеть разницу)

Comment: Хех, несмотря на все его потуги - огромные поля слева.

Comment: Поля слева? Какие?

Comment: это не то что я хочу сделать у них все сбегает вниз мне нужно было сделать все фиксиированым в ширину(что я уже сделал) так что всем спасибо!!!

Comment: @technomaniak1: http://i35.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0417/fc/6735afcaa750abae940fd409535287fc.png

Comment: Это так то отступ....

Comment: Ну может быть, может быть. Но выглядит очень криво :-)

Comment: Ну дизайн такой че уж главное техника)